# Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x5b

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, metaplex, anchor-solana

This is on the frontend of a staking ui.(Locks Metaplex NFTs.).This occured after deployment on mainnet,the same program was working just fine on devnet.

I am using a helius RPC.

Here's the instruction. (All the accounts are initliazed.):
/StakeButton.tsx

```
              const ix = await workspace.program.methods
              .stake()
              .accounts({
                nftTokenAccount: tokenAccount,
                nftMint: fetchednftinfo.mint.address,
                nftMetadataAccount: fetchednftinfo.metadataAddress,
                nftEdition: fetchednftinfo.edition.address,
                stakeAccountList: mintPda,
                        // stakeList: userFixedPoolKey,
                metadataProgram: METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
              })
              
              .instruction()
```

Here is my package.json :

```
    {
  "name": "staking-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "create-bld-token": "ts-node token_mint/token/index.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.8.8",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@project-serum/anchor": "^0.25.0",
    "@solana-mobile/wallet-adapter-mobile": "^0.0.1-alpha.8",
    "@solana/spl-token": "^0.3.4",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.9.9",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "^0.15.8",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "^0.9.11",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.16.9",
    "bs58": "^5.0.0",
    "@metaplex-foundation/js": "^0.15.0",
    "framer-motion": "^6.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "next": "^12.2.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.23",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "eslint": "8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.2",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  }
}
```